# GCC ARM Performance drop

Tags: c++, gcc, arm, embedded, embedded-linux

I stumbled upon very strange issue with GCC. The issue is 25% drop in performance. Here is the story.

I have a pice of software which is fp32 compute intensive (neural networks compiled with TVM). I compile it for ARM (rk3399 device), here is info:

gcc -v

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-linux-gnueabihf
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-5 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libitm --disable-libquadmath --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-armhf/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-armhf --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-armhf --with-arch-directory=arm --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --enable-multilib --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-arch=armv7-a --with-fpu=vfpv3-d16 --with-float=hard --with-mode=thumb --disable-werror --enable-multilib --enable-checking=release --build=arm-linux-gnueabihf --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu/Linaro 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12)
```

uname -a

```
Linux FriendlyELEC 4.4.143 #1 SMP Tue Nov 20 11:10:11 CST 2018 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

lscpu

```
Architecture:          aarch64 
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                6
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-5
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    3
Socket(s):             2
Model name:            ARMv8 Processor rev 2 (v8l)
CPU max MHz:           1800.0000
CPU min MHz:           408.0000
Hypervisor vendor:     horizontal
Virtualization type:   full
```

The code was initially "slow" and cpp11, I decided to try cpp17 and cpp14. cpp17 was not supported, but cpp14 was. I switched to cpp14 and voila I got boost around 25% in performance. I really tested it to make sure the boost is in fact real and not a measuring mistake. I had this boost for a week then my device rebooted and the boost in performance was gone!

It may sound crazy, but I'm very sure in my code and measurements I had. I didn't have explicit compile flags prior to this gimmick. Now I'm trying to figure out compile flags for GCC to reclaim what was lost, but I don't have much experience with GCC. What could be the issue here? What flags can affect performance that much?

the code uses .so files, compiled with use of llvm and gcc

```
llvm -device=arm_cpu -target=armv8l-linux-gnueabihf -mattr=+neon,fp-armv8
```

Comment: where the fetch lines land can alone cause a performance drop like that, very difficult to do accurate benchmarks/measurements.   You would somehow need to profile to find out the most used code, then compare that to see how much of it is instructions, alignment, order of instructions, etc.  Now if you are not using -O2 on gcc (and/or clang although llvm offers more optimization options that gnu) then start there.

Comment: you are also running on an os so there are performance issues there, in particular getting good measurements.

Comment: @old_timer I'm running on version of Linux, I was thinking I'm not getting full clock of ARM-72, are there any tips besides using `nice -n -20` to get full compute of cpu for my binary?

Comment: If the change in performance occurred spontaneously after a re-boot with no code change or rebuild, then the problem is clearly not the compiler.

Comment: @Clifford the boost happened when I changed cpp11 to cpp14 standard and rebuild the code. And the boost was there until reboot of device (sounds crazy).

Comment: @Fortyq : Yes, that is my point - why are you looking for a solution in the compiler code generation if the reduction in performance was not from a change in the generated code?

Comment: Voting to close this as cannot reproduce, since the OP is apparently benchmarking non-optimized code.

Comment: And my experience here on SO has taught me that some 90% of all benchmarking performance problems are caused by incorrect benchmarking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not GCC fault. It's CPU frequency scaling problem. I had device with ARM with Linux (ubuntu) on board, strange behavior and different benchmarking results are due to strange cpu frequency governing by OS.

Answer (score 0):

"What flags can affect performance that much?"

Turning on the optimizer `-O1`, `-O2` or `-O3` can have a dramatic effect (default is unoptimized build `-O0`).

Enabling link time optimization `-flto` can also often give significant improvements.

See also [the manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) for more.

Comment: -Ofast -flto or -O3 -flto have very small effect. The difference was 25% in speed. I assume something is really off, but can't figure out what...

Comment: @Fortyq Be *extremely* careful with `-Ofast`. It improves performance by breaking the standard in some cases, so you can no longer rely on certain things the standard says you are supposed to be able to rely on. You can also get weird results in some corner cases. I'd advice against using it.

Comment: @Fortyq If you don't have any optimization enabled, then obviously this whole discussion is pointless. You should have at least `-O2` before even considering benchmarking.

Comment: @Fortyq If you have found that optimisation settings have  only small effect over _no optimisation_ as indicated in your question, then there is truly something wrong - possibly in your measurements.  Optimisation has a significant impact on all but the most trivial code.

Comment: @Clifford that's true, but the code didn't change and aren't basic optimization flags are in place by default?

Comment: @Fortyq "aren't basic optimization flags are in place by default?" *No*. The *default* is unoptimized build to make debugging easy.

Comment: @JesperJuhl that's not entirely true, if I put -Q -v (and no other options), there I see plenty of flags that impact performance: `options enabled:  -faggressive-loop-optimizations -fchkp-check-write -fchkp-instrument-calls -fchkp-narrow-bounds -fchkp-optimize -fchkp-store-bounds -fchkp-use-static-bounds -fira-share-save-slots -fira-share-spill-slots -fivopts -mthumb -munaligned-access -mvectorize-with-neon-quad ...`

Comment: @Fortyq Not the kind of optimisations that cause the generated code to defeat source level debugging, the have minimal impact despite terms such as "aggressive".