# ARM Frequency control

Tags: arm, embedded, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I stumbled upon following problem:

I have a piece of software written in C++ and a device rk3399 (FriendlyELEC). The issue is performance of the code depends on whether or not display is attached to the device. If I ran my code via ssh (without display attached) I get 25% slower performance rather than if I ran code with display attached.

I figured it's a frequency scaling problem (device runs Lubuntu) I changed profile to `performance` (it was set to `interactive` initially), but that didn't help. I monitored voltage and cpu freq, all seems constant (1.2V, 1.12V) and (1.42 GHz, 1.8 GHz).

It's probably some control that tries to save battery and uses Display Port as decision flag. But I can't figure out what kind it is and where to find it.

Initially I was thinking I have [problem with GCC flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208814/gcc-arm-performance-drop?noredirect=1#comment106530673_60208814) (there could be some relevant info)

How to get the device to run with stable performance? What could be the problem?

Comment: It could be a bug in the display driver constantly trying to get display information when there isn't any.  You can run `top` and if the 'system' times are higher and/or look at the '/proc/interrupts' to see if you have higher numbers without a display.